# How to bundle js files in "dist" folder (angular 7)?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, bundling-and-minification

I am running an angular 7 web application that has a dist folder with bunch of java script files that are not bundled. I would like to bundle all the java script file inside the dist folder in one java script file to minimize the http request when I load my web page

I have tried the following:

```
npm run build --aot --buildOptimizer --prod
```

I am expecting to see bundled files in dist folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your files will not be bundled to a single file. At least several files will be available like `main.js`, `vendor.js` etc.

However, if you want to pass building options like `--aot` you have to run

```
ng build --aot --prod
```

`npm run build` will run exactly the command defined in `package.json`.

Comment: It seems to be working I can see that the files generated were minimized. 
I was hoping to find a way to bundle all js files in one to send only one request to the server.(the way how the webpack does it)
Thanks Sergey!

Comment: If you want to have only one output file you have to run `ng eject` so you will have an webpack.config.js available for edit and change it in appropriate manner.